# Who will be able to see the names and contact information of people who donate to the Stein/Baraka recount efforts?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance

The Stein/Baraka Green Party campaign has launched an effort to [raise money for a recount](https://jillstein.nationbuilder.com/recount) for the presidential election in several states. It asks for the names and contact information for anyone who wishes to donate.

Who will be able to see this contact information (I'm working under the assumption that anybody who can will be sending me mailings in the future). It's especially not clear to me how this works since it's not for trying to elect someone to be president, so I'm not sure if the normal campaign finance rules apply.

Comment: Good question.  I didn't see it explicitly stated anywhere, by my impression is that this counts as a typical campaign donation, with all the baggage/restrictions that go along with it.  It just so happens the campaign is spending money on recount filings instead of ads, but that doesn't change the donation rules.   That said, I'm not positive, and I'm not sure what all the rules for campaign donations are, so this is not, in and of itself, an answer.

Comment: Looks like they are using [Democracy Engine](http://www.democracyengine.com), these may provide some insight: [Terms of Service](http://www.democracyengine.com/subscriber_tos) & [Privacy Policy](http://www.democracyengine.com/subscriber_privacy_policy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Normal campaign finance rules still apply.

---

On Stein's [campaign website](http://www.jill2016.com/recountfaq), it states:

> **Can a wealthy person donate the whole amount you need?**
>
> [...]
>
> The **Federal Election Commission's rules on campaign contributions still apply** here. The good news: If you had donated the maximum amount of $2,700 as an individual contributor **by November 8**, you are now permitted to donate up to $2,700 to fund this recount initiative.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

---

So, contributions to the recount effort would still be considered as campaign donations.

Comment: Good find!  It would help to describe what the normal campaign finance rules, as far as sharing name/contact info, actually are, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Who will be able to see this contact information (I'm working under the assumption that anybody who can will be sending me mailings in the future).

You should assume that Jill Stein and some number of staffers can see the contact information.  Also, they may give it to the Green party.  Or a new party.  Or just someone that they like.  Campaigns pass around contribution lists pretty freely.

If you pay more than $200 for 2016 (previous Stein contributions plus the recount contributions), your contact info will be visible on their campaign finance reports to the [FEC](http://www.fec.gov/pages/brochures/citizens.shtml).  That's visible to pretty much everyone.

Under some circumstances, they might have to turn over the contact information to law enforcement.

Note that most organizations suggest sending the money to something like the Democratic party rather than the recounts.  It is unlikely that this will have any effect on anything.  And remember that they have already funded the filings.  What you are buying now is staff services and recount fees.  You may want to wait a few days for them to give a better estimate of the total costs.  They have enough to file in all three states.

If you do send money, make sure to mark it for the recounts.  That way they have to offer to refund it if they don't use it.

Comment: The campaign has made it clear that the estimate is for both [the filing fees and the attorney's fees](http://www.jill2016.com/why_does_it_cost_so_much) and that any excess money will be used for [promoting election integrity and voting system reform](http://www.jill2016.com/how_will_you_use_surplus_funds). Having them offer a refund isn't likely, since they are being upfront about what it will be used for and what will happen to the excess.

Comment: Also, are there any laws about passing around the contribution lists? Sure, I assume the Green Party has my contact info, but if my contribution isn't greater than $200 and thus isn't public record, are there any laws about who thy can disclose it to?

Comment: No.  The laws center around when they *must* disclose it.  There aren't laws that prevent disclosure.  Probably because most active donors are already in the must disclose state and therefore don't care so much.